# Index outside bounds of the array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to simplify a few long statements with arrays, I've found similar questions on here but I can't work out where i'm going wrong. The code is as follows:

```
if (coursechoice.Text == ("Subsidiary Diploma"))
{               
    var grade = new[] { grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, grade5, grade6, grade7, grade8, grade9, grade10, grade11, grade12, grade13, grade14, grade15, grade16, grade17, grade18 };
    var unitselect = new[] { unitselect1, unitselect2, unitselect3, unitselect4, unitselect5, unitselect6, unitselect7, unitselect8, unitselect9, unitselect10, unitselect11, unitselect12, unitselect13, unitselect15, unitselect16, unitselect17, unitselect18 };

for (var i = 3; i < 18; i++)
{                   
    grade[i].Enabled = false;
    unitselect[i].Enabled = false; // I get index out of bounds of the array here
}
```

The code `grade[I].Enabled= false;` works fine, however its only the unitselect which doesn't work, thanks if you are able to help.

Comment: unitselect14 is missing

Comment: you are missing a 'unitselect14'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unitselect contains only 17 items, there is no `unitselect14`.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I overlooked that haha

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what your intention is with the loop logic, but since you are working with an array (which implements IEnumerable), you may be better off solving your problem using LINQ.

Example:

```
grade.Skip(4).Take(15).ToList().ForEach(g => g.Enabled = false);
```

Linq docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx

**Update**

As per @Gusdor's comment, a standard foreach loop would be better.

```
foreach(var g in grade.Skip(4).Take(15)) { 
    g.Enabled = false; 
}
```

Comment: -1 for `Foreach`. You are creating a new list for the sole purpose of using this method and then throwing that object away. There is no reason to avoid a conventional `foreach`, which has greater affinity with `IEnumerable`. `foreach(var g in grade.Skip(4).Take(15)) { g.Enabled = false; }`. Less characters as well, for those who keep count :P

Comment: Just my 2 peneth, I don't consider .ForEach to be linq per se.  It is an instance method on the List<T> class.

Comment: Does this actually answer the question? Does the OP learn where his mistake was with this answer? I'm thinking no.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and while I can appreciate what you say I think this answer may not be a spot on solution to OPs question, it may well be the introduction to something that made OP learn something new today. And that is worth a lot more than a bunch of SO points.

Answer (score 1):

array index starts from zero u have 17 element in unitselect array so for should be

```
        for (var i = 3; i < 17; i++)
```

Comment: bhau punyat job aasel tar paha na mala... asp.net 2 yrs experience

Comment: passout kadhicha ahes?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1K3q6MmohRtVaobvaBfOf9wGCDB3Pp6h5E9_wTy2260k/viewform ya link var ja

Comment: form aahe ka kasala?(office madhun kholta yenar nahi...ghari jaun open karen)

Comment: TCS offcampus drive ahe

Comment: ohh...thike...mi pahato ghari jaun

Comment: chat la ye bar personal

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41853/discussion-between-f-r-i-e-n-d-s-and-nitin-varpe)

Answer (score 1):

The error would imply you have a different number of elements in the 2 arrays in this specific case `unitselect[]`. Eventually the for loop hits some value of i that exceeds the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You missed unitselect14 element in the array. :)

Comment: Bit slow with that answer. Everone said the same thing ages ago.

Comment: hehe... while i was typing people posted. Got to improve typing speed. :)